# IE7 CSS - label background-color doesn't change on radio button checked

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem in highlight a label when an input radio is checked on IE7.

the code is very simple and you can take a look here: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/hXap6/)**

I need to let it work on IE7 without using Javascript.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input id="yes" type="radio" name="name" title="yes" />
        <label for="yes">Yes</label></li>
    <li>
        <input id="no" type="radio" name="name" title="no" />
        <label for="no">No</label>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

label{
 background-color: yellow;
 border: 1px solid #777;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 30px;   
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 background-color: green;
 color: #FFF;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 7 doesn't really do your CSS3 selector, you will want to use: http://selectivizr.com/ to provide the CSS3 support to IE 7.

Without JS this is impossible to achieve.

You would need to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

To your site to enable IE7 :selector support.

Comment: You'll be best asking the Selectivizr support team for help on that. Note you will need jquery or a similar library as featured on the selectivizr front page for this too work.

Comment: You have added jquery as well?

Comment: Ah, well that's the only solution I can offer. I've tested this locally with Selectivzr/JQuery using your code and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

":checked" is not supported in IE 7

Comment: And your solution to this is...? Answers should generally include solutions to the OP's problem _along with_ a statement about why their problem exists.

Comment: you can use it basically with jquery: $("input:checked").click(function(){$(this).nextAll('label').css({'background-color':'green','color':'#FFF'})})